# Помогите совладать с чтением из файла и записью в файл

Tags: c++

Ниже задача и мой неправильный код.

Считать 5 чисел из текстового файла input.txt в массив, найти максимальное значение среди них.
Записать в файл output.txt новый массив, где каждый i-ый элемент равен разности максимального значения и i-ого элемента изначального массива.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fstream f_in, f_out;
    f_in.open("input.txt", ios::in);
    f_out.open("output.txt", ios::out);
    char Arri;

    short max = -1000;

    f_in.getline(Arri, 255);
    short n = strlen(Arri, 255);
    for(short i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if(Arri[i] > max){
            max = Arri[i];
        }
    }
   for (short i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
       f_out << max - Arri[i] <<" ";

   f_in.close();
   f_out.close();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int arr[5] = {0};
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("1.txt");

    // чтение чисел в массив и определение максимального
    int max = INT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        inFile >> arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }
    inFile.close();

    // обновление массива
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = max - arr[i];
    }

    // запись значение из массива в файл
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("1.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        outFile << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только два вопроса, зачем библиотека <climits>  и почему int max = INT_MIN? Я не полностью привёл задачу, там ещё было ограничение размеров элементов числа Arri (|Arri|≤1000). Поэтому я и взял int max = -1000. Но Ваш код более универсальный.

Comment: для использования константы INT_MIN. Т.е. это минимальное значение, которое можно хранить в типе int.

Comment: А не проще взять в качестве `max` первый элемент, а уже потом сравнивать остальные?

Comment: Можно и так сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема вашего кода в том, что вы не создавали массив, куда бы записывали элементы, я немного подкорректировал ваш код

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::fstream input, outuput;
    input.open("input.txt", std::ios::in);
    outuput.open("output.txt",std::ios::out);

    std::vector<int> input_arr(5);
    for (auto &num : input_arr)
        input >> num;

    int max_element = *std::max_element(input_arr.begin(), input_arr.end());

    for (auto &num : input_arr)
        outuput << max_element - num << " ";

    return 0;
}
```